# Using php regex to split string

Tags: php, regex

I've having trouble splitting this string into components.
The example string I have is `Criminal.Minds.S10E22.WEB-DL.x264-FUM[ettv]`. I'm trying to split it into the following:
`Criminal Minds, 10, 22`.

Though I've dabbled a bit in perl regex, the php implementation is confusing me.

I've written the following:

```
$word = "Criminal.Minds.S10E22.WEB-DL.x264-FUM[ettv]";
// First replace periods and dashes by spaces
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\./';
$patterns[1] = '/-/';
$replacement = ' ';
$word = preg_replace($patterns, $replacement, $word);
print_r(preg_split('#([a-zA-Z])+\sS(\d+)E(\d+)#i', $word));
```

Which outputs `Array ( [0] => Criminal [1] => WEB DL x264 FUM[ettv] )`
Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use matching rather than splitting if the string is always in this format:

```
$word = "Criminal.Minds.S10E22.WEB-DL.x264-FUM[ettv]";
preg_match('~^(?<name>.*?)\.S(?<season>\d+)E(?<episode>\d+)~', $word, $m);
print_r($m);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/YWMT9P)

Then, you can access the `name`, `season` and `episode` values using `$m["name"]`, `$m["season"]` and `$m["episode"]`.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<name>.*?)` -  a named capturing group matching any 0+ chars other than line break symbols, as few as possible, up to the first....
- `\.S` - `.S` substring of literal chars
- `(?<season>\d+)` - a "season" named capturing group matching 1+ digits
- `E` - a literal char `E`
- `(?<episode>\d+)` - an "episode" named capturing group matching 1+ digits

Comment: Thank you. Could you kindly explain a bit regarding the regex itself? Especially this part: `?<season>`

Comment: Yes, I have added the details. The `(?<name>...)` constructs are *named capturing groups* that allow accessing the match parts you are interested in in a more idiomatic way. Note that in case there are other formats, the pattern can usually be adjusted by adding  optional consuming patterns between the `(.*?)` and `\.\S`.